# Data based on first row value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Activity having data like below.It contains multiple rows of `CreatedBY` like `IVR,Raghu and IT`.
But I need to get the data only when the first row of `CreatedBY='IVR'`.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at `TOP` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output?

Comment: @vissubabu . . . Are you sure you don't want the first row for each ticket?

Answer (score 0):

This following query will return firstcreated row for each user (CreatedBy)-

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CreatedBy ORDER BY CreatedBy,[Date And Time])  RN
    FROM your_table
)A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use exists

```
     select a.*
    from table a where createdby='IVR'
    and datetime in
   (select min(datetime) from table b where a.ticketno=b.ticketno
    and createdby='IVR')
```

Comment: This query returning all the created by values

Comment: @vissubabu it will return only one row

Comment: Let me clarify again , I want all the rows where first row of my data contains IVR and it is coming from CreatedBY column...

Comment: Hello Its a activity table and joins with Tickets table.For a selected ticket it has activity log. Actiivty table has many rows like attached image in main question I need to return all the rows if the first value is 'IVR'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want the first row *per `ticket_no`*.  At least, that makes more sense as a query.

If so, in SQL Server, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from activity a
where a.createdby = 'Raghu' and
      a.datetime = (select min(a2.datetime)
                    from activity a2
                    where a2.ticket_no = a.ticket_no
                   );
```

Comment: Let me clarify again , I want all the rows where first row of my data contains IVR and it is coming from CreatedBY column...

Comment: Hello Its a activity table and joins with Tickets table.For a selected ticket it has activity log. Actiivty table has many rows like attached image in main question I need to return all the rows if the first value is 'IVR'